# How can my Android app know if I'm running in Production or Test

Tags: android, mobile

For the most part, my app is a simple app wrapped around the browser.  I suspect regular apps have the same issue, but when I deploy my app for testing, I need to point it to test servers, when I move to production I want it on production.  Currently we deploy one version for testing, change some config, and then deploy a new version and basically skip the testing states.  Seems like there should be a very simple way to do this.

As a bonus, do you know an iOS method as well.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking - it sounds like you're already bundling different configuration for your dev/prod builds, which is a pretty standard approach.  What's the issue here?

Comment: Well, what we do is create a completely new build of the application after we've tested.  So I have build 14 for example that's done with my test configuration that goes up through beta testing, and then I make build 15 that points to production servers that I then skip beta testing as I don't want to test on production.

Comment: Don't you basically have that anyway, given the whole Android debug vs. release build mechanism?

Comment: Did you have a look at Gradle's "product flavors"?

Comment: Obviously I'm new to Android development, I just couldn't find anyone asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can config build.gradle for automatically resolving build types:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
        def TRUE = "true"
        def FALSE = "false"
        def LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS = "LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS"
        def REPORT_CRASHES = "REPORT_CRASHES"
        def ENABLE_VIEW_SERVER = "ENABLE_VIEW_SERVER"
        def ENABLE_SHARING = "ENABLE_SHARING"
        def DEBUG_IMAGES = "DEBUG_IMAGES"

        debug {
            ...
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, REPORT_CRASHES, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_VIEW_SERVER, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_SHARING, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, DEBUG_IMAGES, TRUE
        }

        client {
            ...
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, REPORT_CRASHES, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_VIEW_SERVER, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_SHARING, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, DEBUG_IMAGES, FALSE
        }

        release {
            ...
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, REPORT_CRASHES, TRUE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_VIEW_SERVER, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, ENABLE_SHARING, FALSE
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, DEBUG_IMAGES, FALSE
        }
    }
}
```